# Status code always returns 200 instead of 401 or 409 in python

Tags: selenium, http, web-scraping, python-requests, instagram

I've written an instagram bot. But sometimes i got http errors like 409 or 401. To manage these errors i try to catch them in python but i cannot. Because when i try to get response code it always give 200 but in the background it says http 429. Why is this happens?
My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
time.sleep(5)
baslangic=datetime.now()
yeniliste=[]
a=0
b=0
for i in followlist:
    try:
            follower = driver.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{i}/')
            response = requests.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{i}/')
            response.status_code
            print(response.status_code)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="_aa_c"])')))
            text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_aa_c']").text.upper()
            a=0
            print(response.headers)
            if ("IEU" in text) or ("İEU" in text) or ("İEÜ" in text) or ("IEÜ" in text) or ("IZMIR UNIVERSITY OF ECONOMICS" in text) or ("İZMIR UNIVERSITY OF ECONOMICS" in text) or ("IUE" in text) or ("İUE" in text) or ("IZMIR EKONOMI ÜNIVERSITESI" in text) or ("İZMIR" in text) or ("IZMIR" in text):
                yeniliste.append(i)
                b+=1


    except:
        a +=1
        print("hata")
        print(response.headers)
        if a==3:
            driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since http error 429 means "Too Many Requests", it seems like instagramm detects that you're a bot.

To prevent that, you can buy some cheap proxies and rotate them, such that instagram everytime thinks you're a new device.

Or if you're lucky, only adding some delay after every request might be enough.

Comment: I try using proxie but it didn't help can you help me about that? I used proxied which published are some sites. I added 4 or 5 and i randomly chose it and add my web driver as proxie. But it didn't work. I really cannot get over this problem. I already add long time delay but every time i got these errrors after a while. Even scrolling.

Comment: Did you try scrolling slower? How fast do you scroll? In a human possible way? Or like tarzan?